# How to use Axios globally using composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm having trouble getting Axios to work using the composition API. The following is what I've done, but I'm unsure how to access Axios within setup(). I'm aware that the "this" keyword is no longer available in the composition API.

**Created an axio.js file in /plugins:**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    install: (app, options) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.axios = axios.create({
            baseURL: options.baseUrl,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Authorization: options.token ? `Bearer ${options.token}` : '',
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Added it to plugins/index.js

```
import { loadFonts } from './webfontloader'
import vuetify from './vuetify'
import pinia from '../store'
import router from '../router'
import axios from './axios'

export function registerPlugins (app) {
  loadFonts()
  app
    .use(vuetify)
    .use(pinia)
    .use(router)
    .use(axios, { baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_AXIOS_BASE_URL })
}
```

**Then the main.js file registers all plugins:**

```
import App from './App.vue'

// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'

const app = createApp(App)
registerPlugins(app)

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios